# How to get MoPub to start showing advertisements in Android?

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

I integrated Mopub ads in my application. Application is running fine but in ads banner section all I can see is:

> WELCOME TO MOPUB!
>
> Click Here To Test Ads.
>
> you can now set new campaign to serve other ads.

I cannot find any solution for this like why this is not showing any type of ads.

I have not published my app to play store, only waiting for MoPub to work perfectly fine so that I can push it to play store.

I have Ads unit in app.Mopub.com and its displaying the ads impression and click on dummy text for ads but no actual ads.

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Please don't spoil your titles with requests for "help" or "urgent" - keep it succinct, and bear in mind that questions here generally should be useful to readers long after you have forgotten about them.

Comment: Thanks. much appriciated

Comment: hey, did you get solution ?